# Showing Content from Site in Widget

Tags: javascript, widget

I am quite limited in my knowledge of JavaScript. What I would like to do is have a JavaScript widget that can display some data from my website. The Widget needs to be a bit of script that can be placed on any website.

I'm thinking I'll probably need to create an iFrame. Can anyone suggest some articles or other information to get me started on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JQuery, the have tons of ready-made widgets; ideally if you don't want to dig deeper into core JavaScript.

http://jquery.com/

http://www.mootools.net

http://dojotoolkit.org/

More feature rich:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

'Instant Pleasure' (probably what you are looking for):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/12/45-fresh-useful-javascript-and-jquery-techniques-and-tools/

On a site note, I wouldn't use iFrames, because they can lead to security problems (cross-site scripting), but in general iFrames are a great method for asynchronous HTTP calls to minimize loading times, in fact Apple invented the technique before AJAX was defined.